# pop up not closing sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

If a validation error happens, in this case I use "destroy" "close" and "empty" for closing the dialog box. But when any error like validation or backend error occurs, the dialog box never closes after the fix. I need to rerun the program for closing it. The error arises only sometimes.

```
function Update() 
{
  var txtvalid=validateData();
  if(txtvalid)
  { 
    $.ajax({
      type : 'post',
      url : 'controller/Save.html',
      data : $("#formView").serialize(),
      success : function(json)
      {
        var obj = JSON.parse(json);

        if(obj == "Expired")
        {
          $('#dboxView').dialog("close");
          $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : "ConfirmExpired.html",
            data : {testData : obj},
            success : function(js) 
            {
              window.location="Expired.html";
            },
            error: function (e) 
            {
              $.msgBox({
                title : "ERROR",
                type : "error",
                content : "Connection error"
              });
            }
          });
        } 
        else if(obj.substring(0,1)=="1")
        {
          var data=obj.substring(1);                
          $.msgBox({
            title : "Error Message",
            type : "error",
            content : data
          });
        }
        else
        {
          $.msgBox({
            title : "Message",
            type : "info",
            content : obj
          });
          window.refreshDataTable();
//**********************************************************************
          $('#dboxView').dialog("close");
          $('.view-Brnch-content').empty();
          $('#dboxView').dialog("destroy");
//**********************************************************************
        }
      },
      error : function(e) 
      {
        $.msgBox({
          title : "Error",
          type : "error",
          content : "Error in calling function"
        });
      }         
    });     
  } 
}
```

Comment: your call to the close/destroy methods are only run in certain conditions, because they are within "if" blocks. If you want them to run in other conditions, then you need to copy those lines into the other areas of code as well. That's all.

Comment: thats not the problem .
even if it reach the else part ie; sucess part the dialog box donot close.
.empty function works perfectly

Comment: ok then, silly question but is dboxView definitely the ID of your dialog element? If that line is definitely running, then I can't think of another reason. Unless there's a script error occuring just beforehand which is stopping execution of the JS code. Have you checked your console for errors at that moment?

Comment: NO, when i gave alert after each line, the alert works but the pop up container is still there. its not a problem only in a particular page, but all the pop up pages, it happen only somtimes, that some validation error occour. dont have any pattern

Comment: it **must** have a pattern of some kind. Computers are not random. We just haven't found the pattern yet... And you didn't answer my question - is "dboxView" the id of your dialog element in this page?

Comment: Also, using both "close" and "destroy" should not be necessary. I would use only "close", which leaves the dialog available in case you want to re-open it later. "destroy" means the dialog ceases to exist entirely - you would have to re-initialise it.

Comment: @akhi what errors are shown in the Console? If an error stops JS from being processed, this could prevent the close method from being called.